# Working without window functions in SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite, window-functions

Here's my situation, I'm using nixos for a python application and I have python 3.6.5 installed, sqlite for that version doesn't support window functions, and changing python version is very painful in nixos.
Is it easy enough to avoid using these functions ?
for example how would this snippet of code become ?

```
cast(dense_rank() over(order by period) as int)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically use a subquery:

```
select
    ...
    (select count(distinct t1.period) from mytable t1 where t1.period <= t.period) as rnk
from mytable t
```